# 404 error when accessing tomcat in browser + Ubuntu server

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu

I have deployed my application in UBUNTU server with tomcat 7 and Apache web server , both the server are running fine while am checking through command line in UBUNTU . But when am trying to hit with web browser its throwing 404 Error. Previously it was worked good , please share your suggestions

Comment: Trust me, we are not prophet.

Comment: Do you have any firewall or something that might be blocking the ports?

Comment: MjSG No previously it worked fine and i disabled every firewalls

Comment: what port are you trying to open it on?